# Formatting String To Integer - NumberFormatException d != java.lang.String error

Tags: java, runtime-error, string-formatting

I've been working on an assignment and I've nearly completed it but I've ran into a bit of a snag. I'm supposed to format the output so that the number has commas separating every hundredth place. Ex: 100,100,100,100. I've searched around a bit and have tried implementing different algorithms but the ones I have tried, I run into a NumberFormatException d != java.lang.String error.

My code is as follows:

```
public static void printOutput(char[] num1, char[] num2, int[] sum){

        char[] largest = new char[1];
        char[] smallest = new char[1];
        char[] tmp = new char[1];

        if(num2.length > num1.length){
            largest = num2;
            smallest = num1;
        }else{
            largest = num2;
            smallest = num1;
        }     

        String number1 = new String(largest);
        String number2 = new String(smallest);
        String total = Arrays.toString(sum);



       System.out.printf("%,d", number1);


   }
```

Now, compiling it works but it fails at run time. I suspect that I have buggered something up somewhere..

The output should look like this where everything is aligned perfectly:

```
       39,983,928,349,458 + 
           92,387,486,729
     --------------------
       40,076,315,836,187
```

I assume using a column the length of the largest number would work just fine and then filling everything from right to left but like I said I'm struggling to figure this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Carefully study the Javadoc for `String.format()`, `java.util.Formatter`, and the `System.out.printf()` method.

Comment: Have you considered using `java.text.NumberFormat` and `DecimalFormat` classes? These are designed to format numbers and currencies for specific locales.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an exception you also get a line number in which the exception occurred. In most cases, the line number is more useful than the actual type of exception. In your case you can see that the exception occurred in the line:

```
System.out.printf("%,d", number1);
```

Now take a moment to see what you are trying to do here. The "%,d" part you are trying to print is no ordinary String, it is part of the Formatter. In other words, it tells you how you would like to have your variable displayed. In order to see what it does we need to take a look at the [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) docs. We see that:

```
%    indicates usage of the formatter
,    indicates that "the result will include locale-specific grouping separators"
d    indicates that "the result is formatted as a decimal integer"
```

Now if we read a little further we can also see that the argument category for 'd' is integer. That means that the Formatter takes an integer and displays that according to your desired format. The argument you are feeding to the formatter is number1, which is a **String**!

You need to convert your char array to an int, instead of to a String.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I believed that was the case but ran into a problem trying to parse the char array into an integer. I'm not sure if an integer is big enough to hold the numbers. The assignment I'm working on is supposed to work up to 30 digits. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are indeed right that an Integer is not big enough to hold 30 digits - and neither is a Long. So you're pretty much forced to abandon working with numbers then, but since it seems you're not doing any calculations, you can work with Strings or char arrays. I suggest using Strings and either using the [Decimal Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) class, as [prasad_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679320/prasad) suggested or if that's too advanced for the assignment, making your own loop that adds the separators manually.